# geom_density makes bar shaped graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a density curve for my data with the following code:

```
ggplot(velar_nonnasal_low_f, aes(x = F2_difference, linetype = type)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Density of F2 difference for /æ, ɛ/ for females") +
  xlab("F2 difference") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Place of Articulation")
```

This code has worked fine with previous data frames, but now it produces the plot below instead of a smooth curve. I apologize if this is an easily answerable question (I am still learning R), but I just can't figure out why ggplot is plotting the data this way.

[image]

Here is some code so that you can reproduce a small part of what my data looks like.

Edit: Here is reproducible code of my actual data.

```
 type <- c("coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal", "coronal")
        F2_difference <- c(46.992662, 18.174776, -90.708617, -59.842787, -147.212234, -272.596601, 38.560577, 64.413318, -107.797167, -148.581689, -207.521093, 37.117600, -110.178964, 209.738062, 456.686906, 39.369545, -29.394699, -36.435841, 2.056190, -22.414031, 4.705579, -188.352557, -212.596306, 159.445017, -139.284470, -278.304356, -121.685889, -118.666014, 804.253078, -42.737883, 203.878428, -34.867516, -221.979230, -128.715072, 85.145217

        velar_nonnasal_low_f <- data.frame (type, F2_difference)
```

Comment: I get a totally different smooth curved plot with the data you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was something with my code so I only included a small sample. My entire data set now has reproducible code.

Comment: With the new data, I still get a proper plot. What versions of R and ggplot2 are you using? Perhaps re-start session and try.

Comment: I just downloaded a new R version a few days ago, and ggplot is 2.1.0, and once I restart it is still the same

Comment: I think there is a mismatch between the data given here and the data used to plot the graph. There is only one value "coronal" in type variable data but 2 values are present in graph. If you see closely you have obtained another graph(presumably smooth) corresponding to "coronal". I guess you have very less number of "labial" values. That is why you see plot like the one above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @navinkb is right in his comment. To replicate the graph you have I did this:

```
n <- 33
type <- c(rep("coronal", n),
          rep("labial", 35 - n))

F2_difference <- c(46.992662, 18.174776, -90.708617, -59.842787, -147.212234, -272.596601, 38.560577, 
                   64.413318, -107.797167, -148.581689, -207.521093, 37.117600, -110.178964, 209.738062, 
                   456.686906, 39.369545, -29.394699, -36.435841, 2.056190, -22.414031, 4.705579, -188.352557, 
                   -212.596306, 159.445017, -139.284470, -278.304356, -121.685889, -118.666014, 804.253078, 
                   -42.737883, 203.878428, -34.867516, -221.979230, -128.715072, 85.145217)

velar_nonnasal_low_f <- data.frame (type, F2_difference)

library(plotly)
ggplot(velar_nonnasal_low_f, aes(x = F2_difference, linetype = type)) +
  geom_density() +
  ggtitle("Density of F2 difference for /æ, ɛ/ for females") +
  xlab("F2 difference") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Place of Articulation")
```

I get this:

[image: Modified Data]

But if I use the data you shared I get:

[image: Original Data]

So maybe check the data?